# Google Analytics 4: Get number of users based on a specific event count

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am using Google Analytics 4 (formerly known as “App + Web) in my app. I am sending out an event called `task_completed` to GA whenever a user completes a mini task. Now in GA, how do I make a report or filter that can return the number of users that have performed the task_completed event once, twice, three times or more?

Basically I want to be able to get insights like these:

Users who have performed `task_completed` once = 40

Users who have performed `task_completed` twice = 50

Users who have performed `task_completed` three times = 25

Users who have performed `task_completed` more than three times = 15

Note that the event count for once, twice and three times should be absolute. Meaning someone who has performed `task_completed` 10 times should not be counted into once, twice and three times.

I am almost certain I can do this with a custom audience but the problem is custom audiences are not retroactive so I won't be able to use it on past data. And then it also feels a bit inelegant to create custom audiences for all the basic combinations like the above.

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: the term Google analytics 4 could mean several things can you be more clear?  Are you talking about GA4 ore are you talking about the Google analytics reporting api v4, or i think there is also an android sdk that was v4.

Comment: @DaImTo It is Google Analytics 4 (formerly known as “App + Web). I will update my question.

Comment: so you mean [GA4](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10089681?hl=en) vs Universal analytics.

Comment: Audiences might not work here as I believe user can't leave an audience - which means once they perform task once, they get to group 1; they do it twice - stay in group 1 and go to group 2 as well, which is what you're trying to avoid.
This type of advanced analysis will probably require a connection to Big Query (which can be done for free now)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using segments using the analysis hub (left-hand side nav under "analysis".
[image]

Comment: This is promising but I am not sure why when I try to create a segment with event_count as the condition parameter, the only available numeric operator to select is the larger than > operator.