# Google Analytics 4: How to count users with at least one event occurence?

Tags: google-analytics

**Use case:** I have an event called `is_authenticated` which triggers once every hour if the user is authenticated. Of course I can create an report with "Total users" and filter users based on this event. However, I want to create a metric "Authenticated users", based on this event that I can add as column to various reports. It should work similar to "New users" for example.

**What I've tried:**

- Add two event parameters: `event_prop1=1` and `event_prop2=abc`.
- Add two user properties: `user_prop1=1` and `user_prop2=abc`.
- Create custom metric for all these props.
- If the `abc` value was counted once in total, I could have used the `session_id` instead when triggering the `is_authenticated` event to count once for each user. Unfortunately, only `event_prop1` is counted from all 4.
- Found no way to create a Custom Metric at the User level. I was thinking it could have been used to count Users based on user properties.
- Read about [Custom Metric Averages](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/advanced#event-scoped_custom_metric_averages), but couldn't find how to use in GA4 UI. In case the average is calculated for users with at least one event occurrence, the number of users could be determined as {Some Metric}/{Average Some Metric}.

**Question1:** Is is possible to count users with at least one event occurrence with Custom Metrics? If yes, how?

**Question2:** Is is possible to use "Authenticated Users" as column in reports that consider data for all users? If yes, how?

**Note:** [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65954211/google-analytics-4-get-number-of-users-based-on-a-specific-event-count) does not fulfill my requirements. I need something more simple, but more flexible.